Microsoft Edge "Edit and Resend" Not Showing Up
I am badly facing difficulty in opening XHR Replay in Microsoft Edge.
Please see the Image Below. I tried "Restore To Default" from Dev. Tools but that did not helped either.
Did anyone faced the same issue ?. Please help.
Microsoft Edge Version : 123.0.2420.65 (Official build) (64-bit)
Thank you,
Priyanka


I hate XHR tools in the browser. I use BurpSuite to modify the request/response on the fly. If it is your own API, Use Postman to test it.

Seems like a new issue for Edge DevTools, and I can easily reproduce this problem on 123.0.2420.65. I also have Microsoft Edge with version 114.0.1823.43, where the "edit and resend" feature works fine.
You can try to roll back Microsoft Edge to that version, so you may find it work again. Meanwhile, you can also send feedback to report this issue to the Dev Team using Alt+Shift+I in Microsoft Edge

I'm on the Microsoft Edge team, and just wanted to say that we are aware of this problem and are tracking it with this GitHub issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/224
I love this feature and personally would really like for it to be fixed, but want to set expectations by saying that this was always an experimental feature only, and is unfortunately not sitting at the top of our backlog. We're definitely discussing about it now and will share a plan as soon as we have one.

Hey Patrick, I sent feedback through Edge include screen shot (with official ID, we are big pharma Top 5 company). We literally loved this features. Due to missing of this feature, we are using temporarily FireFox just for this feature only.  Thank you for your support.

I also use this feature religiously and tell other devs it's a reason to switch to Edge.

@Patrick Brosset : Now its fixed, its coming beautifully. Thank you so much.
